# Add more options for which SE a question should migrate to when closing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

I was upset that 4 people voted to close [Godels Incompleteness Theorem(s) and Consciousness is Non Algorithmic](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/godels-incompleteness-theorems-and-consciousness-is-non-algorithmic) as off-topic, by clicking an option that totally dismisses the question, rather than trying to help the new-user by recommending a place for migration.

This question should get at least get a chance at Philosophy SE or maybe Mathematics. When voting to close I clicked "off-topic" then "migration", but the only option was to migrate to Meta:

[image]

Shouldn't we also provide the options to migrate to:

- CS
- Physics
- Chemistry
- Biology
- Cross-Validated
- Philosophy
- Mathematics
- MathOverflow

?

It is not a good thing when a question gets voted to be "closed" but for a reason that does not make any sense.

On ChemistrySE I had this question closed as "too broad":

[image]

But it was razor specific. Not "broad" at all. So I can accept that the chemistrySE community felt it was not appropriate, but the reason they gave did not make sense, and less experienced users might have taken that in a worse way than I did.

Answer (score 6):

There are only a few spaces for migration options/paths which need to be manually created.

In order to migrate a question when there is no migration path, flag for mod attention saying that it should be migrated. If it's not obvious why, an explanation can be helpful, although we can ask mods from the site to be migrated to if it's on topic on that site.

In order to create a migration path, migrations to that site should be required frequently. The only exception to this is the meta of the site the question was posted on.

Quite simply, as we're a small site, we have neither the number of incoming or outgoing migrations to have any migration paths to or from here yet.

**In other words**: yes, it's possible to add more migration paths but we need to actually perform a number of migrations to the site we want to add a path to *first*

For more information on this, see ['Migrate to *any* site?'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86928/349720), including [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86950/349720) on *why* we can't just list an arbitrary number of sites.

Comment: I don't understand why you're saying "Quite simply, as we're a small site, we have neither the number of incoming or outgoing migrations to have any migration paths to or from here yet" ..... yet we have a totally useless migration suggestion listed when closing questions, which is the migration to meta.

Comment: Also, beta sites almost never get migration paths enabled. I'm aware of only a single instance (Writing.SE >  English.SE). Any migrations can simply be handled by the moderators, given the very small amount of questions that actually need to be migrated, user1271772. Setting up a migration path for somewhere you're not already *heavily* sending questions over to... it doesn't really justify its existence. The migration path to meta is standard and is on every SE site, and is the most common use of migration AFAIK.

Comment: No one ever asked for a migration path to be set up. We are asking for the option to be there for selecting when closing a question. So that we can still vote to close the question without lying about the reason for why we are voting to close.

Comment: @user1271772 - there's no way to select "this belongs on <site>" directly from the close UI with*out* setting up a migration path. Anything that's off-topic (which is the only reason why something would be migrated) is covered by the default "not within scope" close reason. If that's not available or you want to add more context, you can select close > off-topic > other and write a custom comment explaining your close vote (e.g. "I'm voting to close this as off topic because it appears to be about Mathematics, not QC. You may have better luck at [math.se].").

Comment: So I don't understand why we can't have an option to suggest physics or maths SE

Comment: It's because it doesn't happen often enough to make it worth it? How hard is it to setup the migration path? The problem is that you don't have the power to do it and someone higher up in stack exchange has to do it for us at our request?