# Custom close reason for questions which might be better suited for Physics SE

Tags: discussion

We recently got a few questions like:

1. [What is the "CP" operation in the context of anti-particles?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/what-is-the-cp-operation)
2. [How can blackholes be fast information scramblers?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4567/how-can-blackholes-be-fast-information-scramblers)

It should be quite obvious that these are not *directly* related to quantum computing or quantum information theory. I have no problems if users want to ask such questions to quantum information theorists or the quantum computing folks. Being too restrictive in the beta stage might actually be counter-productive. I myself had gotten an excellent answer to my question [What is the use of Categorical quantum mechanics?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/what-is-the-use-of-categorical-quantum-mechanics), which, in hindsight, isn't directly related to those either of those fields.

But, I can also empathize with those who *do* feel that [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) would be a better home for such questions. Since we currently do not have any community consensus on this, I would suggest using a custom close reason like:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. In its current form, it does not appear to be about quantum computing or quantum information and is thus off-topic here. It might be better suited for `[physics.se]`. If you feel otherwise, please `[edit]` the question to clarify.

(By the way, `[physics.se]` and `[edit]` written with square brackets are [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242306/405243) ;)

It may not be possible for the moderators to officially add this as a close reason, without requesting the Stack Exchange devs to set up a migration path. Moreover, migration paths are usually set up when *regular* migrations occur from one site to site, and that is quite rare for beta sites like ours. So, for the time being, if you come across such questions, you can use simply create a custom close reason like the one I mentioned above by clicking on `Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)`. Subsequently, if 4 other users vote to close using the manual option created by you, it will be put on hold.

[image]

**Related**: [Add more options for which SE a question should migrate to when closing](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309/add-more-options-for-which-se-a-question-should-migrate-to-when-closing)

Comment: The way I see things here is that there are two options for this question - You're proposing 1. a close reason that's essentially defining a new off-topic reason for QC or 2. a new migration path, saying that the question should be on physics (and not on QC). Once you add a new migration path, that *automatically* becomes a new close reason but just to that specific site, so which option would you rather ask for? (Both is also a valid answer, although I'd start to get a bit more concerned about using up valuable close reasons)

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 I don't know whether it would be a good idea to officially add this as a close reason as of yet. I made this posts for those who want to use this as a manual custom-close reason without having to type the same message again and again. They can simply copy and paste from this post instead. In any case, I'd like to know others' opinions on this - whether they want to make this an official close reason or not. Also, I had the impression that beta sites don't get migration paths anyway - so it may not be useful worrying about that now.