# Add stackoverflow to the "belongs on another site in the SE network" closing option

Tags: feature-request, programming-questions, migration

With the increasing popularity of tools and python packages for implementing and play with QC, more and more questions are getting closer to the edge of being *general coding questions*.

Many of these questions have or can get an answer in StackOverflow as they are generic enough. For example, **only this week**:

- [Multiple Providers on IBMQ](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16176/multiple-providers-on-ibmq) - A generic multithread question, like https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=multiprocessing+%5Bpython%5D
- [IBMQ.load_account() fails with "403 Client Error"](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16128/ibmq-load-account-fails-with-403-client-error) - a *Cloudflare to restrict access* https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=403+%5Bpython%5D+Cloudflare+to+restrict+access
- [Handle Qiskit Excpetion while Loading IBMQ Account using Streamlit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16028/handle-qiskit-excpetion-while-loading-ibmq-account-using-streamlit) - Streamlit does not wait for input https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Streamlit+input

The reasons for putting an items in this list is debatable. They represent just my opinion and they are here to make a broader point: **the need to migrate questions to StackOverflow is growing**. When closing a questions as it "belongs on another site", the option for StackOverflow does not shows up.

A similar (although more generic) question popped up 2.5 years ago [Add more options for which SE a question should migrate to when closing](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309/add-more-options-for-which-se-a-question-should-migrate-to-when-closing)

In this case, I'm arguing for adding just one other SE site.

Comment: I agree that the stackoverflow migration route would be useful, although migration is rarely that great an option in general, see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261200/276202. But the main problem I see is that, as far as I can tell, we don't have that much agreement as to which programming questions are on-topic here and which ones should rather be asked elsewhere. Tbh I personally feel like a significant percentage of [tag:programming] questions here should really go on stackoverflow, although I usually leave them be because others might disagree

Comment: anyway, I don't know if the criteria spelled out in the linked question are met. Migrations can happen regardless of there being a direct path, you just need to flag for moderator attention and say you think the question should be migrated (or same using custom close reason). When enough questions get migrated like this a direct migration path can be made (or at least that's my understanding)

Comment: Assuming I can find the settings for this again, this is certainly doable, but as @glS said, the important thing about migrating is whether the question is off-topic here, not just whether or not it's on topic on the target site

Comment: This is still a problem (another example from today https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27578/qiskit-missingoptionallibraryerror-pdflatex-library-is-required-to-use-latex-c). Is there any news about the migration path?

Answer (score 1):

This question: [How to code density matrix in python?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/17552/2293) got closed due to needing "details for clarity" which is going to be extremely misleading to the user. The real reason it was closed was because the question is a "pure programming" question where they are struggling with doing an "outer product" in Python, which is something that may be more appropriate for StackOverflow.

Still we can debate about whether or not we want to allow such questions here, and indeed the question got an answer (if I had noticed that, I may not have voted to close) but I think the option should still be there to select "This question belongs on another site: StackOverflow" and those who disagree that such questions should be closed can choose not to close vote, but at least the 4 people before me who selected "needs detail for clarity" could have selected something much more appropriate if the option was given there.

Comment: the existence of an answer doesn't generally affect whether a question should be closed. That said, I personally voted to close this one as missing details because that seems the main problem with the question. Migrating poor questions would just end up on it getting closed on the other site.